# Subtraction in dataframe between rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i want an easy subtraction of two values. I want to replace the value in [10, 150] by calculation the value in ([10, 150] - [9, 150]).
Somehow the code does not like the "rows-1"

```
  for columns in listofcolumns:
        rows = 0
        while rows < row_count:
            column= all_columns.index(columns)
            df_merged.iloc[rows, column] = (df_merged.iloc[rows, column] - df_merged.iloc[rows-1, columns])
            rows = rows+ 1
```

It seems to be the case that the `df_merged.iloc[rows-1, column]` takes the last value of the column.
I used the exact same line in another script before and it worked

This would be an example of some columns

```
  Col1        Col2        
  0            2
  0            3 
  0            4
  0            4
  1            5
  1            7
  1            8
  1            8 
  2            8
```

The output dataframe i want would look like this.

```
  Col1        Col1        
  nAn          nAn
  0            1 
  0            1
  0            0
  1            1
  0            2
  0            1
  0            1 
  1            1
```

Comment: please provide an explicit example of input DataFrame and the matching expected output (in a reproducible format)

Comment: please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72736017/edit) the question

Comment: It is all cummulated values over some amount of time. I need the increase or decreas between those intervals, which would simply be the difference

Comment: Please provide the example input/output in a format that can be copy/pasted. It's rather difficult to do testing on an image, and I'm not going to re-write all of that for you.

Comment: I edited it, i hope its enough for an example

Comment: how'd you get the 1 and 1 in the last two rows? shouldnt that be zeros?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want to do, this would be the solution:

```
data = {'A': [5,7,9,3,2], 'B': [1,4,6,1,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["A"] = df["A"] - df["B"]
```

###### DataFrame at the start

```
   A  B
0  5  1
1  7  4
2  9  6
3  3  1
4  2  2
```

###### DataFrame at the end

```
   A  B
0  4  1
1  3  4
2  3  6
3  2  1
4  0  2
```

Comment: I edited the question to get a better impression. I also need to iterate over the index of the columns, since I need this to be done on 200 columns or so

Answer (score 0):

```
df.diff(1)
```

```
    Col1    Col2
0   NaN     NaN
1   0.0     1.0
2   0.0     1.0
3   0.0     0.0
4   1.0     1.0
5   0.0     2.0
6   0.0     1.0
7   0.0     0.0
8   1.0     0.0
```

above is based on the following data

```
    Col1    Col2
0     0       2
1     0       3
2     0       4
3     0       4
4     1       5
5     1       7
6     1       8
7     1       8
8     2       8
```